# Scraping and modifying Word document text with bold font

Tags: python, web-scraping, docx

I have a Word document with multiple-choice questions. The question is bold, and the answer is bold. I would like to modify the text this way:

Before:

```
[bolded question]
a) [option]
b) [option bolded meaning it is an answer]
c) [option]
```

After script:

```
[bolded question]
a) [option]
b) [option bolded meaning it is an answer]
c) [option]

{{c1::b) [option bolded meaning it is an answer]}};
```

Essentially I want to modify the document to take the text of the answer, copy and paste it below the question, apply "{{c1::" to the beginning of the answer and "}} ;" to the end of it. Is there a python script I can create to do this?

I've tried putting this prompt in ChatGPT with little success, here is some of the code it made:

```
import docx
    
# Load the Word document
document = docx.Document('input.docx')
    
# Loop through all paragraphs in the document
for i, paragraph in enumerate(document.paragraphs):
        
    # If the paragraph has at least one run and it is bolded
    if paragraph.runs and paragraph.runs[0].bold:
            
        # Get the question text
        question = paragraph.text
            
        # Get the answer text
        answer = document.paragraphs[i+1].text
            
        # Construct the new answer text
        new_answer = "{{c1::" + answer + "}} ;"
            
        # Add the new answer paragraph below the question
        document.add_paragraph(new_answer)
            
# Save the modified document
document.save('output.docx')
```

It places the `{{c1::[answer]}}` on the bottom of the doc